# Using XAML in WinForms

Tags: winforms, xaml

I want to use XAML to generate classes at compile time in a complete WinForms app. I don't want to use WPF although I am open to suggestions.

It seems like this should be possible but I can't find any information about exactly how. The closest thing I've found is this page: http://anoriginalidea.wordpress.com/2007/12/13/weird-science-defining-winforms-in-xaml/

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to gain by doing this?

Comment: I want to write XAML and have that turned into C# classes at compile time.

Comment: But why? What is wrong with typical factories to generate classes? What are you looking to gain in using XAML over a typical factory approach?

Comment: I don't understand what you are suggesting exactly. I want to use XAML to define the object graph which makes up my view and then have a code behind file like WPF does. I can see other applications though.

Comment: So you want to mimic WPF in WinForms. I was getting at the fact that it doesn't seem to be simply class instantiation you want to accomplish, you want to use XAML for your View and then C#/VB for your code behind. It won't work in this instance. Why can't you use the WPF stack in its entirety?

Comment: I have existing code and I don't want to just throw it all away. I also would like to use it for POCO objects as well but that's not my main focus.

Answer (score 3):

It's a common misconception that XAML = WPF, it doesn't. I'd suggest looking at CODE + MARKUP = Applications book by Petzold. Though I suspect that it won't cover Winforms per se. I've always planned to try this but never got round to it. Good luck.

Comment: I know that XAML != WPF and that's why I think what I want to do should be possible. I just don't know how.

Comment: @smack - I can see that. I was pre-empting any answers that may have made that mistake.